# Cross-site auth in modern browsers without 3rd party cookies

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, safari, local-storage, privacy

There are several parts of the system at different domains (not subdomains). I need to authenticate user at all domains after he has logged in at any of them without any interaction from user.

In the old days I used cookie at the common domain. Now it's not possible - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/chips/

Then we used iframe with LocalStorage and postMessage to the parent window - https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage . It also has stopped working recently because now different domains have separate LocalStorage for the common domain - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/storage-partitioning/

Chrome has announced possible solution: SharedStorage - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/shared-storage/ But:

- it doesn't work in Safari (MacOS and iOS users are important to us)
- you have to apply as a company and enroll your domains (not a problem for us but not convenient for stage and dev environments)

I see only one bulletproof solution:

- redirect all unauthorized users to the common domain
- common domain generates random token (or takes it from cookie/localstorage if exists) and redirects back to the original URL with this token
- domain tries to use this token to authenticate
- if not authenticated then add this token during login/registration so next time it will autologin user
- during logout remove this user token so it's not valid any more

This is terrible UI for user - 2 additional redirects; and seems like overcomplication.

May be there is a nicer solution that will work in modern browsers?

Comment: you can use an hidden iframe with redirect to same domain, generate token, redirect again with token to other domain, postmessage  to main window

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti this approach will not work because iframes of the common domain will have different cookies embedded to different domains. This is what cookie CHIPS is about https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/chips/

Comment: @luchaninov safari has not banned 3rd party cookies though, they instead ask for permission with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/requestStorageAccess i might be jumping the gun but did you consider running with 2 auth systems, 1 using cookies and 1 the shared storage for chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is structured in two part, a first part is about high-level design, the second part is about the specific technical issue in question.

## High-level design

> There are several parts of the system at different domains (not subdomains).
> I need to authenticate user at all domains after he has logged in at any of
> them without any interaction from user.

I am going to talk relative to the more abstract concept of application domains / sites:

In the ideal scenario, there are multiple applications plus a separate one dedicated to *authentication* and, more generally, to *identity* services.  (Incidentally, note that *authorization*, i.e. handling the specific roles and privileges that might be associated with an identity (a user) *given a specific context*, are in fact usually application specific and do not pertain to the identity service.)

> I see only one bulletproof solution:

> - redirect all unauthorized users to the common domain

Yes, though a redirect is not strictly needed: your identity service might simply expose web services and the single applications interact with it behind the scenes on behalf of the user.  But a redirect remains the canonical solution, not just to avoid code duplication, but especially, where it is relevant, so that any registration / login / manage account experience stays unified across all applications.

> - common domain generates random token (or takes it from cookie/localstorage
>   if exists) and redirects back to the original URL with this token

Generates new token, period.  And stores it on the server for later use, *verification* in particular (see below). -- I have no references for this, sorry, but I'd give it as the security best practice that an authenticated user that lands on the login page gets automatically logged out (the cookie removed and/or any stored token associated to the login revoked): this keeps the user flow "clean".

> - domain tries to use this token to authenticate

Specifically, once the user has authenticated, whence have got their auth token, they would submit it with every request to any of the applications: what the application has to do at that point is *verify* the token (which is standard terminology and includes decrypting the payload), which it again would do by leveraging a web service exposed by the identity service.

The token usually carries identity information directly in the payload: the idea is enough information for any specific application to be able to identify the user uniquely and proceed with any authorization if needed.

> This is terrible UI for user - 2 additional redirects; and seems like overcomplication.

Indeed, redirecting to a login page, to be then redirected back to the page the user was trying to access, is the canonical solution, especially if users explicitly register / manage their own account and profile: if that is not needed, e.g. in an Intranet context or in machine to machine authentication, just wrapping around a dedicated web service may be enough.

## Technical issues

That much said for an architectural overview, there is one technical problem in particular I should mention, all the more so since it is explicitly in the question:

How can the token generated upon successful login be forwarded by the client to any other application page if the login page is in a separate domain from the application itself, so we incur cross-domain limitations.  There are in fact several ways we can solve this problem, and I am simply going to quickly mention the most common ones and the ones I could think of:

- **CORS and cross-domain cookies**: maybe the cleanest and most appropriate for our purposes.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
  This might have problems with ad-blockers and similar since these are considered third-party cookies: on the other hand, it does not sound unreasonable to ask users to add exception rules related to the domain/domains in question, as long as they do want to login and use the applications...
- **Redirecting with HTTP Status Code 307**, for POSTing the token back to the application.
  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-307-temporary-redirect
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307
  I have no direct experience myself with this, but people, e.g. here on SO, say that browsers ask the user for confirmation before allowing the redirect, though I could not find any reference to this requirement in the official documentation [ADD: it is anyway allowed by the statement "The user agent *MAY* use the Location field value for *automatic* redirection" (my emphasis), whence the redirection *may* not be automatic]: but, if it is true that most browser behave that way, this might very well not be a good solution in our scenario, it makes for a poor user experience for no substantial reason.
- **Returning** an HTML page, with hidden fields including the token, in **a form that then gets submitted by JS** automatically at page load.
  I think this would also be an acceptable solution, as far as user experience goes, indeed it is not very different from the usual client-side redirects with the page showing "automatically redirecting in 3,2,1... secs: click this link if that does not work".  The potential drawback again is that this would not work with JS disabled, on the other hand, as above, a user who browses the web with JS disabled is certainly not unaccustomed to clicking a link or pushing a submit button in order to proceed.
- **Opening the login page in an iframe and using the `window.postMessage` API** to exchange the result token cross-domain.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
  This one requires some more client-side coding, it also has the previously mentioned limitations of all JS-based solutions, but, where it is reasonable to expect that users enable JS, this one is also a viable solution that works quite well in my experience.
- **Shared local storage and similar experimental features**.
  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/shared-storage/
  Any "special" features that are not yet widely supported by the browsers I would think are not viable here: an exception would be a context in which there is full control over the browsers in use, but this is a kind of scenario that I think is simply disappearing: in our age of universal access and work anywhere anytime anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have only one source of truth for auth - at the common domain. But how to autologin user without user interaction and without redirect? (you've written "though a redirect is not strictly needed")

Comment: You say "autologin" and I don't know what you mean exactly.  The fact is either you now reformulate/expand the question with stricter requirements, possibly considering the flow and variants I have mentioned (in terms e.g. of who needs to authenticate, whether there is account management involved or it is plain login, whether it is acceptable to have the login page not be offered by the identity service itself, what you in fact mean by "autologin", etc. etc.), or I find it not possible to give more specific advice than the above.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that what you are describing is very similar to either an OAuth 2.0 Authorization flow, or possibly Open Id Connect (OIDC)

Rather than attempting a totally custom system you might do better to restructure your system to follow an open web standard, making you less likely to fall foul of future changes.

Yes you need to create your own identity server and it does involve redirects *but* having used the Microsoft Azure / Azure AD implementation across multiple systems as both a user an a developer, it is not a terrible user experience.

There are many blogs, tutorials or 3rd party products that support these flows. Searching for "OAuth 2" or "Open ID Connect" + your language/framework of choice will get you started

Comment: When user comes to the site I don't know if user event has the account. With redirect solution I have to redirect all users for autologin or wait until they push the button "Login"